# Adding an autoincrementing SNO column in Rails Scaffolding?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, automation, scaffolding, scaffold

Is there a way in which I can create a serial number (SNO) column through scaffolding in Rails which increases on adding a record, decreases on deleting a record and cannot be modified manually?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to create a summary column on a model you will need to put this logic into your models. There is not a built in method for this (like a standard autoincrement field), but it can be added easily:

```
class Parent << ActiveRecord::Base 
    # Contains a field: summary_field
end 


class Child << ActiveRecord::Base

   after_save => :increment_summary
   before_destroy => :decrement_summary

   def increment_summary
        Parent.find(self.id).summary_field.increment
   end 

   def decrement_summary
        Parent.find(self.id).summary_field.decrement
   end 

end
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear whether there is any relationship involved, but it sounds like counter_cache may be a good fit.

A [Railscast episode](http://railscasts.com/episodes/23-counter-cache-column) provides the code examples and a video tutorial.